# Flash game file on my site does not run

Tags: flash

I've got this Flash game on my site.
Problem is that it's running a while then it turns white.
Don't think the file is buggy, as i see the same game featured on many other sites without problems.
Any ideas what could cause this behavior?
here it is:
http://www.gratisspiele-downloads.de/onlinespiele/red-ball-3/spielen.htm

Comment: the whole page is white or just the flash?

Comment: How did you put the game on your site?

Comment: Just the flash turns white. Rest of page is OK.
I've put the game on the site like all other games. You can see the embed code in the html of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this issue has already been solved/evolved.

It just had to load a while (~10 MB). While loading, the SWF stayed white. Just [use a preloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410774/how-to-create-preloader-in-as3) for better user experience.