# ASC2.0 and Frame metatag

Tags: actionscript-3

Apparently, the new ActionScript Compiler 2.0 no longer supports the old [frame] metatag which allowed you to add preloaders to pure actionscript projects.

I've verified this IntelliJ - switching the "Prefer ActionScript Compiler 2.0 for pure ActionScript build configurations" makes a difference between the preloader being instantiated and executed, and the main class being instantiated and executed.

Googling yield no result, so is there currently any way around this issue - use ASC2.0 but have the benefits of the Frame metatag?

Comment: I've recently started using ActionScript Compiler 2.0, and I haven't encountered this issue. I use the commandline tool `mxmlc`, and the `-frame` parameter (seems to be) working as before. Since you're talking about a pure ActionScript project, `mxmlc` should be an option for you too (unless it actually is being ignored and somehow my project is still working!)

Comment: @Dave I am using the frame metatag, maybe that's the reason? Can you post exactly what you type for the "-frame" command-line parameter?

Comment: I run it like this `mxmlc Loader.as -frame=ContentFrame,Main`, which makes Loader.as into frame 1 and Main.as goes on a frame labelled `ContentFrame`. I actually don't use ContentFrame though, instead I wait until the SWF has loaded and use `new (getDefinitionByName( "Main" ) as Class)( )` to create an instance of it within the Loader's class. It means that I get more control over animations.

Comment: @Dave Can you please post the way you do it as an answer? I've just checked and it seems to work with the -frame compiler option.

Comment: OK, I posted it. I guess this question is answered, but the better solution would be for Adobe to re-add the meta tag!

Comment: @Dave Thanks for adding it, marked it as correct. Maybe one day they will add it... Or notice that there is something not exactly right with it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still works when using the `mxmlc` commandline tool;

```
mxmlc Loader.as -frame=ContentFrame,Main
```

(produces a 2-frame SWF; the first has no name and contains Loader, the second is named ContentFrame and contains Main).

Comment: Just to clarify, the second argument to `-frame` must be a fully qualified class name, e.g. `-frame=ContentFrame,com.example.Main` unless of course your `Main` class is in the root namespace.  :)