# Does ASC 2.0 recognize [Frame] metadata tags (ex: for Preloader factoryClass)?

Tags: flash, compiler-construction, metadata, frame, mxmlc

I'm trying to use the new ASC2.0 compiler in the AIR SDK 3.7, but I seem to be running into a problem where it cannot detect my preloader class.

If I use the non-ASC2.0 compiler, it recognizes and compiles the Preloader class declared in the Frame metadata tag in my Main class, like so:

```
[Frame(factoryClass = "Preloader")]
```

But as soon as I compile it with ASC2.0, it disregards the Frame metadata and just tries to compile the Main class and assume that it HAS to be a subclass of Sprite / MovieClip (which it does not necessarily have to be when it is Preloaded with a Frame metadata tag), so it fails to compile.

If someone can confirm this that'd be great, been spinning my wheels on this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: FYI to others wandering here, for a tutorial on using a preloader class in a pure AS3 project, see this [excellent tutorial](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=946)

Comment: It's worth noting though that tutorial was written "pre" ASC 2.0, so it may only still apply to the standard SDK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, it is no longer supported. There was a similar question asked here:

[ASC2.0 and Frame metatag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722403/asc2-0-and-frame-metatag)

The new solution seems to be this:

**You have to manually add the compiler arguments for the `-frame` data.**

However, to get this working, you have to setup your project a bit differently from the `[Frame]` metadata technique.

> Before (when using the old `[Frame]` metadata technique), you had to
>   specify your Main class as the Document class (which would then
>   compile and redirect the main entry point to your designated Preloader
>   class).

Now with ASC2.0, instead, you will **set your Preloader class as the Document class**.

Here's a few things you must setup:

- Your **Preloader** class should *extend* **Movieclip** subclass.
   (This makes it possible for your Main content to embed on *Frame #2*)
- Assign your "Preloader.as" class (or however you called it) as the Document class.
- Put this **Additional Compiler Argument**:
  `-frame=AnyFrameLabelYouWant,YourMainClass`
- Also, add the SWF version with this **Additional Compiler Argument**:
  `-swf-version=18`  (though I think 17 will work with ASC2.0 as well...)
- Make sure you are using the **ASC2.0 SDK** compiler in your IDE!

**NOTE**: *Now that I think about it, maybe it's possible to inject `/** @mxmlc */` JavaDoc comments to give the instructions to the compiler, but I didn't try this yet. That may be a workaround for the lack of Metadata support in the ASC2.0 compiler. (edit: I tried this once and this feature only seems to work with the "Build" toolbar button in FlashDevelop, which only compiles the currently focused file)*